# Cannot store string into another variable through looping

Tags: javascript, string

```
for (var j=0, new1=""; j<fs.length; j++) {
    new1[j] = fs[j];
    console.log(new1[j]);
    console.log(fs[j]);
}

console.log(fs[j]) // is displaying the value contained in fs.

console.log(new1[j]) // is displaying "undefined" only.
```

Why is the variable `fs` is shy in giving its value to `new1`?

Comment: Strings aren't arrays.

Comment: you need to concatenate the new string

Comment: Sorted it out using an array.   new1.push(fs[j]);

Comment: couldn't get it done using concatenation.  new1[j] += fs[j];

Comment: @learningQA: Can you post that comment as an answer? It might help someone else in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using string, I've used array and sorted it out. I've created an array and added characters into it using push() method.
new1.push(fs[j]);